# Run Tinytest with Velocity

Tags: javascript, testing, meteor

How can I run Tinytest with Velocity in my Meteor application?
I added package to project:

```
$ meteor add numtel:velocity-tinytest
```

create test.coffee in path /tests/tinytest and run:

```
$ meteor --test
```

or super hardcore:

```
$JASMINE_CLIENT_UNIT=0 JASMINE_BROWSER=PhantomJS JASMINE_CLIENT_INTEGRATION=0 JASMINE_SERVER_UNIT=0 VELOCITY_DEBUG=ture DEBUG=true NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT  meteor --test
```

And the tests don't run.

Jasmine tests are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. The numtel:velocity-tinytest package was pulled from Atmosphere due to conflicts with changes in Velocity's API (https://github.com/numtel/velocity-tinytest)
2. Quick typo: you have Velocity_Debug=ture instead of Velocity_Debug=true

Comment: `numtel:velocity-tinytest` is not usable. I chose `mike:mocha`